# _mm_load_ps caused segment fault

Tags: c++, x86, sse, simd, memory-alignment

I have a code snippet. The snippet just loads 2 arrays and calculates dot product between them using SSE.

Code here:

```
using namespace std;

long long size = 3200000;

float* _random()
{
    unsigned int seed = 123;
    //    float *t = malloc(size*sizeof(float));
    float *t = new float[size];
    int i;
    float num = 0.0;
    for(i=0; i < size; i++) {
        num = rand()/(RAND_MAX+1.0);
        t[i] = num;
    }
    return t;
}

float _dotProductVectorSSE(float *s1, float *s2)
{
    float prod;
    int i;
    __m128 X, Y, Z;

    for(i=0; i<size; i+=4)
    {
        X = _mm_load_ps(&s1[i]);
        Y = _mm_load_ps(&s2[i]);
        X = _mm_mul_ps(X, Y);
        Z = _mm_add_ps(X, Z);
    }

    float *v = new float[4];
    _mm_store_ps(v,Z);

    for(i=0; i<4; i++)
    {
//        prod += Z[i];
        std::cout << v[i] << endl;
    }

    return prod;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QCoreApplication a(argc, argv);
    time_t start, stop;
    double avg_time = 0;
    double cur_time;
    float* s1 = NULL;
    float* s2 = NULL;
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
    {
        s1 = _random();
        s2 = _random();
        start = clock();
        float sse_product = _dotProductVectorSSE(s1, s2);
        stop = clock();
        cur_time = ((double) stop-start) / CLOCKS_PER_SEC;
        avg_time += cur_time;
    }
    std::cout << "Averagely used " << avg_time/100 << " seconds." << endl;
    return a.exec();
}
```

When I run, I got segment fault. Here is the backtrace:

```
(gdb) bt
0  0x0804965f in _mm_load_ps (__P=0xb6b56008) at /usr/lib/gcc/i586-suse-linux/4.6/include/xmmintrin.h:899
1  _dotProductVectorSSE (s1=0xb6b56008, s2=0xb5f20008) at ../simd/simd.cpp:37
2  0x0804987f in main (argc=1, argv=0xbfffee84) at ../simd/simd.cpp:80
```

Diassembler:

```
0x8049b30          push   %ebp
0x8049b31  <+0x0001>         push   %edi
0x8049b32  <+0x0002>         push   %esi
0x8049b33  <+0x0003>         push   %ebx
0x8049b34  <+0x0004>         sub    $0x2c,%esp
0x8049b37  <+0x0007>         mov    0x804c0a4,%esi
0x8049b3d  <+0x000d>         mov    0x40(%esp),%edx
0x8049b41  <+0x0011>         mov    0x44(%esp),%ecx
0x8049b45  <+0x0015>         mov    0x804c0a0,%ebx
0x8049b4b  <+0x001b>         cmp    $0x0,%esi
0x8049b4e  <+0x001e>         jl     0x8049b7a <_Z20_dotProductVectorSSEPfS_+74>
0x8049b50  <+0x0020>         jle    0x8049c10 <_Z20_dotProductVectorSSEPfS_+224>
0x8049b56  <+0x0026>         add    $0xffffffff,%ebx
0x8049b59  <+0x0029>         adc    $0xffffffff,%esi
0x8049b5c  <+0x002c>         xor    %eax,%eax
0x8049b5e  <+0x002e>         shrd   $0x2,%esi,%ebx
0x8049b62  <+0x0032>         add    $0x1,%ebx
0x8049b65  <+0x0035>         shl    $0x2,%ebx
**0x8049b68  <+0x0038>         movaps (%edx,%eax,4),%xmm0**
0x8049b6c  <+0x003c>         mulps  (%ecx,%eax,4),%xmm0
0x8049b70  <+0x0040>         add    $0x4,%eax
0x8049b73  <+0x0043>         cmp    %ebx,%eax
0x8049b75  <+0x0045>         addps  %xmm0,%xmm1
0x8049b78  <+0x0048>         jne    0x8049b68 <_Z20_dotProductVectorSSEPfS_+56>
0x8049b7a  <+0x004a>         movaps %xmm1,0x10(%esp)
0x8049b7f  <+0x004f>         xor    %ebx,%ebx
```

I am using QtCreator and defined in .pro file:

```
QMAKE_CXXFLAGS += -msse -msse2
DEFINES += __SSE__
DEFINES += __SSE2__
DEFINES += __MMX__
```

Please tell me how to fix that problem !

Comment: Related: [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/32612190) describes how to do aligned allocations in C and C++.  (64-bit code often gets 16-byte alignment for free on all dynamic allocations, but alignof(max_align_t) in 32-bit code is often only 8.)

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You are not ensuring that your data is 16 byte aligned (`malloc`/`new` are not sufficient in general) - you will either need to use `_mm_loadu_ps` instead of `_mm_load_ps` to deal with your potentially misaligned data, or preferably use a suitable method to allocate aligned memory (e.g. [posix_memalign](http://linux.die.net/man/3/posix_memalign) on Linux).

Note that you should `_mm_load_ps` and 16 byte aligned memory if you possibly can, otherwise use `_mm_loadu_ps` but note that this may reduce performance signficantly on some (older) CPUs.

Comment: Hi Paul, I'm new to intrinsics programming. I have a look at _mm_loadu_ps and known the address doesn't need to be 16-byte aligned. But please tell me, how to ensure the data 16-byte aligned ?

Answer (score 0):

Try the link below.
http://flyeater.wordpress.com/2010/11/29/memory-allocation-and-data-alignment-custom-mallocfree/

You basically allocate a bit more memory than you need, then calculate the address which is modulo 16 and use memory beginning from that address to load/store data.
Take care of pointer arithmetic.

Most of the code here ideone.com/fXKQhR is taken from the above link, sample usage.

Answer (score 0):

I think, the `_mm_malloc` maybe helpful with you.