# Can I pass unaligned size to _mm_malloc?

Tags: c, memory-management, alignment, sse, allocation

[The documentation I've found so far on `_mm_malloc()`](https://software.intel.com/sites/landingpage/IntrinsicsGuide/#expand=4653,525,3,4701,4695,4602,4601,97,3289,4601,4602,97,4601,1191,1197,1192,1194,4701,1170,5200,5152,5200,5159,5223,5213,5213,4652,4601,611,4923,4077,4226,2270,4886,5098,4223,4222,3780,638,639,640,644,5226,4079,4077,3044,3003,640,640,639,640,5224,5212,5213,5212,5214,2753,5238,4602,4929,2810,2900,3567,2097,417,415,406,417,415,419,2802,2810,2278,2297,3923,5003,3924,3923,1383,1508,300,2278,395,406,3271&techs=AVX,AVX2,FMA,Other&text=mallo) is quite scarce. Particularly, I can't figure out what will happen if I pass it a `size` parameter that is not a multiple of `align`. Is it UB? Or will it allocate the number of bytes which is the next larger multiple of `align`?

Answer (score 2):

These are two independent factors: `size` dictates the raw size, `align` is simply the placement of the allocated block. In actual code you might see a correlation, the reason you want something aligned is usually because `size` is an even multiple of some factor, but it's not a hard requirement.

You may have a perfectly valid reason for allocating 79 bytes aligned on an 8 byte basis.

Comment: Any reference for that?

Comment: Given how important undefined behaviour is so it's always mentioned when relevant (e.g. invalidating pointers), and how there's zero mention of it in the documentation for that function, there's no reason to believe that undefined behaviour is a factor here. This is just an allocator, nothing fancy. If you want to allocate something really odd that's not undefined behaviour, but it might *lead* to undefined behaviour if you put a mis-aligned structure in it.

Answer (score 1):

Intel's documentation for `_mm_malloc` [in their own compiler](https://software.intel.com/en-us/node/523368) only says "This [align] constraint must be a power of two."

There's no requirement that size be a multiple of alignment, because the main use-case for it is SIMD, where it's totally normal to allocate an array with alignment greater than the width of a single member.  (e.g. a `float*` aligned to 32B for AVX).   Or for cache-line / page / hugepage boundaries.  e.g. to take better advantage of transparent hugepages, you might allocate with 2MB alignment for any allocation greater than 2MB.

**The only aligned allocator I'm aware of that *does* have the limitation you're worried about is [C11 / C++17 `aligned_alloc`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/memory/aligned_alloc)**, which is unfortunately required to fail when `size % align != 0`.  See my answer on [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612190/how-to-solve-the-32-byte-alignment-issue-for-avx-load-store-operations).  TL;DR: The original C11 `aligned_alloc` was UB with non-multiple-of-align sizes, so real implementations chose to make it work as expected like other aligned allocators (e.g. `posix_memalign`).  But then it was changed to being *required* to fail (return an error) in that case, instead of UB, so implementations that allowed it to work are technically violating a (stupid) standard.  C++17 has the required-to-fail version.

Obviously Intel didn't make the same mistake that the standards committee did with `aligned_alloc`, because it would defeat the purpose of `_mm_malloc` for optimization.  Of course they had the SIMD and memory-boundary use-cases in mind.  (IDK how the standards committee *didn't*, seems totally obvious as the main use case for types/buffers with more alignment than the natural alignment of the widest type.  It's really disappointing that the one function with the nicest API is not safe to use.  (`aligned_alloc` returns memory freeable with `free`, and doesn't defeat optimization by taking the address of the pointer as an input like `posix_memalign` (which leads to compilers worrying about aliasing).)

> Or will it allocate the number of bytes which is the next larger multiple of align?

That might be effectively true for small alignments like 32B or 64B.  Depending on the implementation, it might not leave that slack space at the end available for smaller allocations with `malloc` or with smaller-alignment calls to `_mm_malloc`.  It's safe to read up the the alignment boundary without faulting (if it's less than a 4k page), but don't write to it if you didn't explicitly allocate it.

In any good quality implementation, it's exceedingly unlikely that a large alignment will waste multiple whole pages.  You could always test by doing many allocations with huge alignments (like `_mm_malloc(3M, 2M)`) and some allocations that could use that space  (like `_mm_malloc(512k, 4k)`), then `sleep(100)`.  Look at the memory footprint of your process before it exits.

Comment: Peter, So `_mm_malloc(numElemets * sizeData, 64)` is fool proof for everything up to and including `AVX512`?