# _declspec(align(16)) does not align the pointer to 16 bytes

Tags: c++, sse

So I am trying to use the SSE function `__mm_load_128`, I am very new to SSE fo forgive me if I have made some silly mistakes somewhere.

Here is the code

```
void one(__m128i *arr, char *temp)
{
    // SSE needs 16 byte alignment.
    _declspec (align(16)) __m128i *tmp = (__m128i*) temp;

    if (((uintptr_t)tmp & 15) == 0)
        printf("Aligned pointer");
    else 
        printf("%d", ((uintptr_t)tmp & 15)); // This prints as 12

    arr[0] = _mm_load_si128(tmp);
}
```

I get an error on visual studio
`0xC0000005: Access violation reading location 0xFFFFFFFF.`

`0xFFFFFFFF`  does not look right, what am I doing wrong.

`arr` argument is initialized as `_m128i arr[5] = { 0 }`

Alternative would be to use `_mm_loadu_128` which works fine but as I understand it, It should produce `movdqu` instruction but this is the assembly generated

```
    arr[0] = _mm_loadu_si128(tmp);
00D347F1  mov         eax,dword ptr [tmp]  
00D347F4  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [eax]  
00D347F7  movaps      xmmword ptr [ebp-100h],xmm0  
00D347FE  mov         ecx,10h  
00D34803  imul        edx,ecx,0  
00D34806  add         edx,dword ptr [arr]  
00D34809  movups      xmm0,xmmword ptr [ebp-100h]  
00D34810  movups      xmmword ptr [edx],xmm0
```

Thanks guys, From the answers I realize I have made couple of mistakes.

1. Align the source use `_alinged_malloc`
2. Compile with optimizations.
3. Use C++ casts not C

Comment: You are not doing anything to align source address. You are trying to align pointer without changing the stored address. You should ensure that buffer pointed to by `temp` is properly aligned instead. Also you should avoid C-style casts in C++ code.

Comment: @VTT: `(__m128i*)` is standard style for intrinsics.  `reinterpret_cast<__m128i*>(temp)` is generally too bulky, and Intel's intrinsics have long enough names already.  (Also, `__m128i` is allowed to alias any other type, so it's special.)

Comment: Don't compile with optimizations disabled if you want sane looking asm output.  Emitting `imul edx, ecx, 0` is just a hilariously bad way to zero `edx`.  It is doing a `movups` load, but then spilling to a temporary on the stack and reloading (with aligned loads) before storing again to where it actually wants the result.  Like I said, enable optimizations if you want the asm to look like what you imagine when writing the C++.

Comment: The sad part here is that it *won't* crash on newer versions of MSVC and ICC because they will often use unaligned accesses anyway. So instead of crashing, you get hard-to-detect performance hits instead. Unfortunately, the MSVC devs said this is by design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I can see three problems here:

1. this code is strictly C, and not C++. it's not a problem per se, but the question is tagged as C++.
2. You don't distinguish between the *alignment of the pointer* vs *the alignment of what the pointer points to*
3. when the code flow is inside `one`, it's impossible to change the alignment of `arr` or `temp`.

Let's focus on point number 2 for a second - there's a pointer, and there's what the pointer points to. I guess you already know the difference between these two.

basically , when you write `_declspec (align(16)) __m128i *tmp` you tell the program:

> When you allocate the pointer `tmp` on the stack, make sure the the first byte of `tmp` is allocated on an address (on the stack) which is dividable by 16.

So great, `tmp` itself is aligned to 16, it doesn't affect at all **what tmp points to**. you need `temp` to point to align data already. this can be done by

1. allocate the data on the stack with proper `alignas` keyword (`alignas(16) char my_buffer[16*100];`)
2. allocate dynamic data with memory allocating functions capable of allocating align data, like `aligned_alloc`, or MSVC's `_aligned_malloc` which requires `_aligned_free`.  See [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612190/how-to-solve-the-32-byte-alignment-issue-for-avx-load-store-operations/32612833#32612833)

You cannot align memory retroactively, it has to be allocated aligned in the first place. make sure the data passed by `temp` is already aligned, or use unaligned loads/stores if you can't require callers to pass aligned data.

Comment: If you compile it as C++, it's C++.  You can say it's written in a C-like style, but that doesn't change how the compiler interprets it.  There are subtle differences between C and C++.  Perhaps this code came from a C example, and the OP is using it in C++.

Comment: you can also write `__asm{mov eax, 8}` and compile it inside a C++ program, but that doesn't make the assembly language C++.

Comment: I mostly agree with that, but still think you should word your point 1 differently.  If you want to criticize the use of C style in C++ code, sure.  But that doesn't mean it's C.  Union type punning would still be undefined behaviour (except that I think MSVC does define it, same as GNU C++.)  But you could argue that in some ways it does make the asm part of a MSVC++ program.  MSVC inline asm has small differences from MASM (e.g. it accepts `0xdeadbeef` as well as `0deadbeefH`.)