# Why does this AVX intrinsic cause "Segmentation fault" with clang, but not GCC?

Tags: c++, clang, inline-assembly, intrinsics, avx

It seems two functions below can cause segmentation fault when compiled with clang using -mavx (or -march=sandybridge -> skylake).

```
void _mm256_mul_double_intrin(double* a, double* b, int N)
{
    int nb_iters = N / ( sizeof(__m256d) / sizeof(double) );

    __m256d* l = (__m256d*)a;
    __m256d* r = (__m256d*)b;

    for (int i = 0; i < nb_iters; ++i, ++l, ++r)
        _mm256_store_pd((double *)l, _mm256_mul_pd(*l, *r));

}

void _mm256_mul_double(double* a, double* b, int N)
{
    int nb_iters = N / ( sizeof(__m256d) / sizeof(double) );

    __m256d* l = (__m256d*)a;
    __m256d* r = (__m256d*)b;

    for (int i = 0; i < nb_iters; ++i, ++l, ++r)
        __asm__(
            "vmulpd %[r], %[l], %[l] \t\n"
            : [l] "+x" (*l)
            : [r] "m" (*r)
            :
        );
}
```

When N is 2 fold or more of 4 (ymm register width / double width), the clang compiled code sometimes cause segmentation fault. (see wandbox link below)

GCC compiled code seems okey.

[godbolt.org/g/YPa7mU](https://godbolt.org/g/YPa7mU)

[wandbox.org/permlink/kex4e3lRCKfPAq2J](https://wandbox.org/permlink/kex4e3lRCKfPAq2J)

** I found the original source code here on stackoverflow.com

Comment: @BeeOnRope I don't claim anything at all. wandbox.org does : https://wandbox.org/permlink/kex4e3lRCKfPAq2J

Comment: It's not just the intrinsics, writing `*l` is already wrong.

Comment: With gcc (didn't check clang), you can do `typedef double uvec __attribute__ ((__vector_size__ (32), __may_alias__, __aligned__ (1)));` and use uvec instead of `__m256d`, this lets the compiler know that it should produce unaligned loads/stores. Note that gcc tends to align arrays more than required, for performance reasons, which might explain why it "works" in your case, although it could also be purely random.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The answer is right there in the asm you linked on Godbolt:

gcc uses `andq $-32, %rsp` to align the stack by 32, so all the alignment-required loads and stores in your code don't fault.  (Dereferencing a `__m256d*`, and `_mm256_store_pd` instead of `_mm256_storeu_pd`).  AVX instructions don't generally require alignment, but the aligned-move instructions (like`vmovapd`) do.

---

This is *only* possible for gcc because your test-case lets the functions using `__m256d` operations on `double a[]` and `double b[]` inline into the function that allocates the array on the stack.

For example:

```
void ext(double *);
void foo(void) {
    double tmp [1024];
    ext(tmp);
}
```

compiles to simple allocation with no over-aligning the stack.

```
    subq    $8200, %rsp
    movq    %rsp, %rdi
    call    ext(double*)
    addq    $8200, %rsp
    ret
```

The x86-64 SysV ABI only requires 16B stack alignment.  (And gcc doesn't choose to maintain more than that.)  So if `ext()` was actually one of your functions that required 32-byte alignment of the `double*`, it would fault.

gcc doesn't know that 32B-alignment would be a performance boost for `ext()`, so it doesn't spend the instructions to align all automatic-storage arrays.  If there's a correctness problem, that's your fault!

---

Clang doesn't do any alignment even after inlining, and just reserves space on the stack with `subq  $248, %rsp`.  So even in your test-case, stack address-space randomization will only give you a 32B-aligned stack half the time.

---

If you used `alignas(32) double a[]`, all compilers would be required to align the array.  (`alignas` doesn't work for dynamic storage like `new` or `malloc`, but it does work for automatic and static arrays.  For dynamic, see [How to solve the 32-byte-alignment issue for AVX load/store operations?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32612190/how-to-solve-the-32-byte-alignment-issue-for-avx-load-store-operations)).

Comment: Is there any way to force alignment of an array on clang?

Comment: @sandthorn yes, with C++11 `alignas(32)`, see updated answer

Comment: How can I put "alignas" into function parameter to give more restraints? If not, will there be one in "Concept"?

Comment: @sandthorn: You can't.  IDK if a future version of C++ would let you make it a compile-time error to pass an under-aligned array to a function that requires aligned pointers, and track minimum-alignments of pointers as they're passed around.  (It is helpful for compilers to know when pointers are aligned, especially gcc with default `-mtune=generic` or Sandybridge/Ivybridge, where gcc splits unaligned 256b loads/stores into 128b halves with `vmovdqu` / `vinsertf128`.  (So it's actually less efficient if it turns out that the pointer is aligned at run-time.)

Answer (score 2):

Probably down to memory alignment, however, modern processors can read/write unaligned memory as efficiently as unaligned memory (well very very nearly as efficient) so use `_mm256_loadu_pd(r)` instead of `*r` and `_mm256_loadu_pd(l)` instead of `*l` and also `_mm256_storeu_pd` to store the variable.

Comment: @Paul R, yes I forgot to mention making the store unaligned, however, the aligned load will still be a problem.

Comment: @PaulR vmulpd cannot take both arguments from memory... Anyway intrinsics work at a higher level than that and don't know about memory vs registers. And `*l` is equivalent to `_mm256_load_pd`, even if in some cases it can be optimized away.

Comment: @MarcGlisse: yes, that's true. Perhaps keith can clarify this in the answer then.

Comment: @Paul R, I won't begrudge someone writing a better answer. I've found intrinsics are a bit of a black art to learn what works and how to avoid surprises. I'm not sure I can summarise that scientifically.

Comment: @keith: sorry for the noise - I didn't read the original question properly - down-vote changed to up-vote.